# How to fill CircularProgressBar with multiple colors

Tags: iphone, ios, quartz-core

I have implement CircularProgress Bar using this tutorial [Link](http://www.turnedondigital.com/2011/quartz-tutorial-how-to-draw-in-quartz/)

But I want to fill this CircularProgress Bar with two or three color not with only one color. How I can do this please help me out.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: you want fill only edge of the circle?

Comment: Yes!In that demo we have circle fill with red color but I want it to fill with two more color.

Comment: Did you find any progress in this? I almost need something similar to this.